# Diferença entre decimal e numeric

Tags: mysql, tipagem

Os dois tipos de dados, `DECIMAL` e `NUMERIC`, são/podem ser usados para armazenar valores exatos.

Por exemplo:

Existe alguma diferença entre `Salario DECIMAL(5,2)` e `Salario NUMERIC(5,2)` no MySQL?

Há alguma situação que obrigue o programador/DBA a utilizar um ou outro?

Comment: Não sei quanto ao MySQL, mas segundo [essa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1842031/520779) de acordo com os padrões do SQL o `NUMERIC` precisa ter a precisão *exata* especificada, enquanto o `DECIMAL` precisa ter *pelo menos* a precisão especificada (mas pode ter mais). As implementações, entretanto, podem ou não tratá-los como iguais - o SQL Server por exemplo não faz distinção entre os tipos, o que está em conformidade com os padrões; não conheço informações sobre como isso é feito no MySQL.

Comment: [O MySQL também não faz distinção.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Comment: @mgibsonbr - Essa postagem que você linkou foi muito esclarecedora. Considere transforma-lá em uma resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segundo o SQL2003 *standard* (§6.1 Data Types), cujo trecho relevante você pode ver transcrito [nessa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/759606/520779) (o *standard* em si não é livre para consulta, precisando ser comprado), estabelece uma pequena diferença entre esses dois tipos:

- O `NUMERIC` precisa ter a precisão *exata* especificada, bem como a escala;
- O `DECIMAL` precisa ter *pelo menos* a precisão especificada, e a escala idêntica.

Em outras palavras, se uma implementação optar por representar o `DECIMAL` com maior precisão do que o requisitado, ela é livre para fazê-lo. Mas se ela quiser implementá-lo com a precisão exata - tornando esse tipo funcionalmente equivalente ao `NUMERIC` - isso também está de acordo com o padrão.

O MySQL - como [apontado por bfavaretto nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54176/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-decimal-e-numeric#comment111157_54176) - é um dos que não faz distinção entre os tipos (o SQL Server é outro). Segundo a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html), no MySQL "`NUMERIC` é implementado como `DECIMAL`", de modo que seu comportamento é idêntico. E, como exige o padrão, a precisão utilizada é exatamente a requisitada.

Sobre utilizar um ou outro, não tenho experiência suficiente para comentar, mas o argumento do Maniero na [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54189/215) de que o uso de `DECIMAL` pode prejudicar a portabilidade (i.e. potencialmente provocar resultados diferentes quando o banco é migrado de um SGBD para outro) já é um boa razão, na minha opinião, para se evitar esse tipo.

Answer (score 6):

Para o MySQL eles são sinônimos. O padrão SQL define que há uma diferença entre eles mas o MySQL simplificou isto e só o comportamento do `NUMERIC` foi implementado. Então é questão de gosto usar um nome ou o outro.

Algumas pessoas dirão para usar o `NUMERIC` quando quer definir uma quantidade específica de dígitos e `DECIMAL` quando quer definir uma quantidade mínima de dígitos. O MySQL não vai respeitar isto mas se mudar para outro banco de dados já estará certo. Porém tem tantas outras coisas mais complicadas de compatibilizar e se mudar de banco a menor das preocupações é a sintaxe. Na verdade é provável que seja pior fazer isto porque se mudar de banco fazendo isto provavelmente mudará a semântica e os resultados poderão mudar. Então se está preocupado com uma possível futura mudança do fornecedor de DB e considerando que o MySQL só implementa a semântica do `NUMERIC`, use só ele. Mas reforço que esse será o menor dos seus problemas se quiser mudar de fornecedor.

Se pensar em portabilidade também evite usar `DEC` ou `FIXED` que são outros sinônimos.

A [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) diz que o truncamento depende do sistema operacional. Este é um motivo para tomar cuidado com seu uso. Outras informações relevantes [nesse capítulo](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math.html).

Eu sei que alguns programadores preferem um usar um inteiro multiplicando as casas decimais. Ou seja, se vai trabalhar com duas casas de centavos o valor gravado é sempre vezes 100 para manter a escala. As aplicações que acessam o banco devem saber lidar com isto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: _"Eu sei que alguns programadores preferem um usar um inteiro multiplicando as casas decimais."_ verdade :) inclusive, eu incluo o fator no nome do campo, para não ter que complicar a documentação do software e evitar enganos naturalmente. Ex: `valor100`, `quantidade1000`.

Answer (score 2):

> Os tipos NUMERIC e DECIMAL são implementados como o mesmo tipo pelo MySQL, como permitido pelo padrão SQL92. Eles são usados por valores para os quais é importante preservar a exatidão como, por exemplo, dados monetários. Quando é declarado um campo de algum desses tipos a precisão e a escala podem ser (e normalmente é) especificadas

Segue abaixo alguns links que explicam bem sobre estes tipos de dados:

[http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/pt/numeric-types.html]
[http://www.rcoli.com.br/2012/08/tipos-de-campos-no-mysql-saiba-como-escolher-o-tipo-correto/]