# Tipo Double e tipo Decimal, qual adequado para valor monetário?

Tags: mysql, sql, tipagem, valor-monetário

Achei aqui no SO uma pergunta com uma resposta até bem aceita pela comunidade [Que tipo de dados (double, float ou decimal) eu deveria usar para representar moeda em .NET com C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11340/que-tipo-de-dados-double-float-ou-decimal-eu-deveria-usar-para-representar-mo)

Só que eu nunca tive problemas com o `double` para cálculos monetários, tive sim com `float` esse ai já me deixou de cabelo em pé, então a partir desta resposta afirmando que o Decimal é o correto, ou isso é apenas p/ quem usa C# e nada a haver com MySQL, comecei a testa-lo, e me deixou um pouco inseguro, por exemplo dizer que vou armazenar sempre 2 dígitos de ponto flutuante, tem casos onde o usuário vai "necessitar" (exceção) fazer o registro do valor com 4 dígitos no banco que por sua vez irá gravar apenas os dois primeiros, por este motivo me sinto mais seguro com `double`.

**Pergunta** - existe um exemplo código fonte que me mostre esse "erro" de arredondamento do Double para eu ver para crer, ou uma fonte de referencia livro, site confiável que sinalize essa recomendação do uso Decimal para registrar valores monetários em **MySQL**?

**Obs 1** - Os tipos de dados me refiro são do MySQL pois também vi uma citação do MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/364x0z75.aspx só que é referencia de C# e me perdoem aos adeptos a MS preciso de uma fonte mais "segura" quando digo site confiável ( pois estou falando de MySQL, não SQL Server, .Net, C# etc.)

**Obs 2** - Tem um link do **próprio MySQL**  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html meu inglês não é muito bom, vejam se estou equivocado, diz:

> *maximum number of digits for DECIMAL is 65*

Numero máximo de digitos para *DECIMAL* É 65

E na sequência diz

> *Before MySQL 5.0.3, the maximum range of DECIMAL values is the same as for DOUBLE*

Ou seja o maior *DECIMAL* é igual ao *DOUBLE*.

Continuando o texto do site

> *but the actual range for a given DECIMAL column can be constrained by the precision or scale for a given column*

Essa parte pelo que entendi é o *DECIMAL* que fica limitado pela precisão ou estou enganado ?

Vou colocar aqui um teste, espero que alguém me demonstre esse "erro" da mesma maneira (semelhantemente)

```
CREATE TABLE `teste` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `numero` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test`.`teste` (`numero`) VALUES ('0.1');
INSERT INTO `test`.`teste` (`numero`) VALUES ('99.9');

SELECT sum(numero) FROM teste;

mysql>     SELECT sum(numero) FROM teste;
+-------------+
| sum(numero) |
+-------------+
|         100 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: fiquei na dúvida pois achei um link onde um "moderador" diz que o Mysql 5.x depreciou o tipo Decimal http://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/76609-double-decimal-ou-float/

Comment: Olha o erro do float, bem claramente. E o double tem o mesmo problema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d5af/2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eu duvido que você nunca teve problemas. Eu acho que você nunca percebeu o problema. A maioria dos casos vai errando por 1 centavo. Claro que erros de 1 centavo podem se transformar em milhares de reais quando multiplicado.

O motivo de tanta gente usar errado é justamente porque o erro não costuma ser tão evidente e nos casos onde ele se torna um problema enorme a pessoa não sabe validar.

Em contabilidade, 1 centavo de erro destrói o trabalho. Em outras atividades pode só dar prejuízo, muitas vezes pequeno, ou pode dar processo vindos de parceiros comerciais ou governo. Não vou entrar em detalhes porque não sou advogado.

Tem um [*site* confiável onde diz isto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/628637/221800) e ele é o Stack Overflow. Tem [várias referências nele](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/221800).

[Nessa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101) eu organizo vários *links* para outras perguntas/respostas sobre o assunto. Se você seguir todos os *links* lá terá todas as informações que precisa. Poderá aprender que o problema ocorre por causa da representação binária dos números que impede de representar todos os números com precisão.

Uma [referência na documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-float.html). [Teste executando no SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5ca81/1).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Other/RoundProblem.sql).

Imagino que todo mundo que participa destas respostas, mesmo que apenas através de votos, concordam que o tipo `DECIMAL` deveria ser usado. Acho que já seriam várias fontes e a variedade obtida em um local onde o que se posta é validado por seus pares, dá uma boa confiabilidade.

No *link* postado no comentário, uma pessoa diz que os tipos `DECIMAL` e `NUMERIC` estão obsoletos. Peça para ele citar a fonte. Provavelmente ele não entendeu a pergunta ou não sabe do que está falando. Ser moderador não significa que ela entenda do assunto que trata o site. Para saber mais sobre estes tipos tem uma [pergunta aqui no site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54176/101).

Alguns exemplos de imprecisão podem ser obtidos no [artigo da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Um simples 0.1 já é problemático. Vou mostrar em C# porque é a linguagem que trabalho melhor entre as *mainstream* mas o "erro" é do processador, e não da linguagem, isto vale para PHP, JS, SQL, etc. Somar 0.1 em um `double` 100 vezes, deveria dar 100, correto? Porque então dá 99.9999999999986?

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        double x = 0.0d;
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) x += 0.1d;
        WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/A07wvg). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eNiRFO). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/RoundProblem.cs).

```
$x = 0.0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) $x += 0.1;
echo $x;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/LQ5L0O). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/cjqwbnmx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Math/RoundProblem.php).

Algumas coisas foram sendo adicionadas depois à pergunta.

Se você acha que o *site* da Microsoft tem alguma informação que não é confiável, cabe a você provar que tem algo errado. Se ninguém mais reclamou, deve estar certo. Se o problema é porque o *site* é da Microsoft e ela é uma empresa toda errada, aí eu não vou conseguir te convencer de nada porque você acredita em Saci Pererê também.

As citações da documentação do MySQL não tem nenhuma relação com o problema. Mas pelo menos nela mostra que os tipos citados anteriormente não estão obsoletos. O tipo `DECIMAL` não tem nenhuma imprecisão, o número que você coloca nele, é o número que será usado, ao contrário de `DOUBLE` que usa um número aproximado ao que você tentou armazenar nele. Claro que o `DECIMAL` terá quantas casas decimais que você determinar. É óbvio que meio centavo não poderá ser armazenado em um `DECIMAL` com apenas duas casas decimais. Mas é decisão do programador resolver isso de acordo com o cenário. O `DOUBLE` muda o valor e isto ocorre independente da vontade do programador.

Entenda o problema lendo tudo o que eu passei e você perceberá que a afirmação "Ou seja o maior DECIMAL é igual ao DOUBLE" é completamente falsa. Como eu disse, as citações não falam do "problema do arredondamento" por causa da representação binária.

O tipo `DOUBLE` pode até esconder um pouco melhor o erro do `FLOAT` mas em algum momento ele aparecerá e não é tão difícil.

Pode ser útil: [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101)

Comment: eu vou ler e seguir os links e material que você já indicou, pelo mesmo motivo que acredito na sua resposta, não é porque algum Moderador ou usuário com boa reputação falou que seja verdade, vou procurar me aprofundar, procurar um código que exemplifique esse "problema" que possa ser colocado num ambiente de teste e "provar" esse erro.

Comment: esse problema de somar 0.1(acho que com 99.1 isso?) nao ocorre problemas no mysql da 100 redondinho

Comment: Não sei como você está testando.

Comment: editei a pergunta com um exemplo de código, li suas referências cai na questão do C# e .net que não é o caso, aqui minha dúvida é se isso também se aplica ao MySql

Comment: bigown me desculpe se lhe ofendi falando sobre confiança na MS, só explanei que ela não é referencia para o meu caso (MySql) e deixei isso bem claro na pergunta, ref. ao Saci Perere, creio que você deveria dar alguma credibilidade ao site do próprio MySql uma vez que de lá que vem o programa em discussão aqui.

Comment: Não. Ela é uma referência para o seu caso, ela pode não ser a melhor mas ela é. Você acha que não é porque você ainda não entende o porquê deste erro ocorrer. Quando você ler tudo e entender, verá que não faz diferença que tecnologia você está usando ou de que empresa. Todos os produtos são dependentes de como o processador funciona. De qualquer forma tem aí uma referência oficial um exemplo executando mostrando que o problema ocorre facilmente. O seu exemplo só não foi suficiente para apresentar o erro, mas outros são. Você não pode pegar um exemplo que funciona e achar que todos funcionam.

Comment: E para quem deu negativo, por favor me informe onde está o erro para eu corrigir. EU odeio postar coisa errada.

Comment: pois é, eu usei o seu exemplo, por isso fiz a pergunta, EU nunca encontrei o erro, por isso que a pergunta foi feita, alguém como você é a pessoa certa ( acredito ) para demonstrar, eu estou quase convencido que o Decimal seja o mais apropriado, só não achei a "falha" no Double que esta citando.

Comment: @bigown Desculpe estar voltando nesta pergunta tão antiga, mas por quê esse problema com o float e double ocorre? Tentei ler o wikipedia que você deixou mas não entendi muito bem.

Comment: @Francisco veja se alguma ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/valor-monet%c3%a1rio?sort=votes&pageSize=50.