# Tipo de coluna para tabela de apoio

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, tipagem

Eu tenho uma tabela cliente e gostaria de criar uma tabela de apoio para evitar criar muitas colunas (endereço, telefone, telefone1, email, email1, email2, placa do carro, nome da mãe, etc.).

A tabela de apoio consistem em no código do cliente, campo e valor.

Exemplo:

```
Cliente: 1
Campo: placa_do_carro
Valor: ABC-1234
```

Qual tipo de dado eu devo usar na coluna "valor" para que eu possa guardar de tudo? (esquema abaixo)

Estou confuso porque nessa tabela pode entrar renda que normalmente seria um `float` e placa do carro que seria um `varchar`.

Estrutura:

Tabela: cliente

```
cliente_cod     cliente_nome    cliente_email
1               José Silva      jose@email.com
```

Tabela de apoio: cliente_campos

```
INT             VARCHAR(20)         ????
cliente_cod     campo               valor
1               placa_carro         ABC-9329
1               apelido             Zezinho
1               renda               5.0000
```

Comment: Esta pergunta apareceu pra mim na lista de análise porque foi votada como não clara. Bom, pra mim ela está clara (e votei pra deixar aberta). Eu só não acho que você deveria fazer o que está propondo. Qual é o ganho esperado em ter linhas em uma tabela para o que deveriam ser colunas na tabela do cliente? O seu sistema vai ser customizado (isto é, o usuário pode ele mesmo definir "novas colunas")? Se a resposta for não, eu facilitaria a vida e criaria colunas na tabela cliente mesmo. :)

Comment: Concordo com o Luiz, isso não é nada boa ideia.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Este padrão chama-se [*key value pair*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database). Está técnica é útil em certos cenários específicos onde é necessário ter flexibilidade de quais colunas serão preenchidas, até mesmo colunas poderem ser criadas sob demanda de acordo com cada entrada de dados (cliente no caso da pergunta).

Não vejo com bons olhos o seu uso neste caso, mas pode ter alguma necessidade que não está descrita na pergunta. Está perdendo muito da vantagem do banco de dados relacional. Se isto **realmente** é necessário, é de se pensar se o MySQL é o sistema certo para a aplicação.

O tipo mais provável é usar um `varchar` que permite colocar qualquer informação. Evidentemente que toda gravação e leitura exigirá que a aplicação faça o devido tratamento. Eventualmente pode ter que usar um `blob` (pouco provável). O MySQL agora aceita um tipo JSON que é uma especialização do `varchar`, pode ser útil neste caso.

Se não tiver um dicionário de dados seria interessante gravar o tipo do dado também para evitar ter que ficar confiando no programador acertar o que tem lá. Provavelmente deve ter algumas funções auxiliares para fazer a conversão do dado na hora de gravar e de ler os dados da coluna. Para cada tipo precisará pensar em um formato de gravação.

Também pode ser difícil fazer consultas diretas ao banco desta forma. Deve-se pensar bem se vale a pena adotar esta estratégia.

[Tem certeza que renda é um `float`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59010/101)? Se isto está mal definido outras coisas podem estar.

Comment: Não faça isto. Leia!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Pensei em usar float(10,2) para renda.
Também havia pensado em registrar o tipo de dado e tratar na aplicação. Gravaria então 5000.00 e float(10,2) como tipo de dado. No PHP eu trataria isso. A verdade é que estou em dúvida se esse é o melhor caminho pra mim. Quero evitar ter uma tabela com 30 colunas. Vou ler já!

Comment: Ninguém pode dizer qual é o melhor caminho para você. Mas se não souber o que vai fazer, o melhor caminho é fazer o que sabe. Mas usar `float` para dinheiro é a única coisa que posso garantir que é um péssimo caminho em qualquer situação.