# No MySQL qual tipo de campo é adequado para guardar peso em gramas?

Tags: mysql, tipagem

Tenho essa dúvida, qual tipo de campo usar para peso como 0.900, 1.200, 2.000, 0.100 e poder tratar os campos como número na saída da query?

Comment: Utilize um float

Comment: Como fomato o padrão do float para unidade de peso ?

Comment: Vc vai tratar os valores onde?

Comment: Se for com php, pode ser até um varchar, quando receber a variável dá pra tratar da forma que você quiser

Comment: Preciso armazenar os valores como citado na pergunta, 0.900, 1.200, 2.400, 0.100, sempre 3 casas decimai depois do ponto, e até 4 casa decimal antes do ponto.

Comment: É, recomendo varchar, acho todos tipos numericos vão cortar caso tenha um 0 após o ultimo número, eu não posso te afirmar isso com total certeza, mas quando for tratar com php por exemplo, da pra fazer o que quiser

Comment: Está dando trabalho com varchar, defini como double 10,3 mesmo. Está respondendo bem.

Comment: 0.010, 1.000, 0.301, 0.001, está guardando normal, obrigado brother.

Comment: Na vdd nem ajudei kkkk, não tenho muita experiência com dbs, mas espero que dê tudo certo aí

Comment: É que se você define como varchar, depois fica mais trabalhoso tratar esses valores como inteiros, para por exemplo, realizar soma para um cálculo de frete, aí tem de fazer manobras, se guardar em campos do tipo que trata números, aí menos código, obrigado.

Comment: Antes de mais nada, "peso em gramas" é o comum no S.I. Na pergunta você fala em gramas, mas 0.900 me parece estar dizendo em quilogramas. Ou é isso mesmo, menos de um grama? Seriam então zero virgula nove gamas, ou seja, novecentos miligramas? Se for para armazenar em gramas mesmo, geralmente o melhor campo é inteiro. Se for fracionário, besteira armazenar em gramas, escolha unidade menor. O que não teria cabimento seria usar float ou string, seja lá qual for o caso.

Comment: @Bacco tem um caso interessante para usar `float`, na verdade o único caso cabível de usar esse tipo de dado: cálculos científicos que pode perder precisão dentro de um limite aceitável (normalmente relacionado ao limite da medição; se o limite da medição de peso for 5 mg, então há um erro intrínseco de medida de 2.5 mg e qualquer precisão além disso já é irrelevante perante a medida; outro caso é quando a medida é obtida indiretamente, então há erro que vem carreado não só pela medida propriamente dita, mas também da operação matemática, como desvio padrão). Mas científico aqui não parece ser

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado de fato eu supersimplifiquei no "qual foi o caso", eu mesmo conseguiria pensar uns casos válidos, mas pequei na retórica pelo espaço do comentário + contexto. Ou seja, tem razão, este que você mencionou é um contexto válido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que o fato de ser em *gramas* não diga muita coisa, pois não existe um tipo de campo para cada tipo de medida: *grama, quilo, metro, quilômetro etc.*

Você pode usar o tipo [decimal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html), que é recomendado para valores envolvendo decimais:

```
          -------------↓ 3 decimais
          ↓           ---
decimal(4,3) // ex. 0.900
        ↑           -----  
        --------------↑ 4 dígitos no total, sendo 1 inteiro
```

Answer (score 6):

A pergunta não tem informação suficiente para cravar um tipo. Além disto afirma que tem que gravar de uma certa forma, mas não diz o porquê. Vejo em muitas situações a pessoa achar que tem que ser daquele jeito, mas poderia ser de outro jeito. A pergunta não fala se 0.900 são 900 gramas ou 900 miligramas.

Eu gravaria como inteiro, ou seja gravaria com a menor unidade possível, provavelmente miligramas, assim não dependo da parte decimal. E trataria na aplicação sobre isto. Mas nada impede o uso de um tipo decimal, e este tipo provavelmente deveria ser o [`DECIMAL`. O `FLOAT` ou `DOUBLE`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101) podem ser adequados se o problema permitir inexatidão, eu [prefiro trabalhar com números exatos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59010/101).

Da mesma forma que [não deve usar um tipo numérico para dados descritivos só porque eles só aceitam dígitos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101), não deve usar um tipo de texto para dados quantitativos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Confere o título: "No mysql qual tipo de campo é adequado para guardar peso em GRAMAS?" E no corpo da pergunta, usei gramas, pois a pergunta é sobre gramas. E trato a entrada no DB antes de armazenar, pra eventuais "inexatidões", mas deu certo, obrigado por tudo, pelo seu ponto de vista que tem agregado conhecimento ao meu trabalho.

Comment: Continuo sem saber se .900 são 900 gramas ou 900 miligramas, assim como 1.200 são 1,2 gramas ou se são 1,2 Kg, a informação contínua ambígua. Pra mim .900 são 900 miligramas e po isso eu gravaria os miligramas. Dar certo é diferente de estar certo. Como não vi o que fez não posso afirmar se apenas deu certo ou se está certo. Eu trabalho com precisão de informação, só assim dá para saber se está certo ou não. Quando a informação está incompleta ou ambígua não dá para confiar no resultado, está se fazendo apenas uma aposta que pode dar certo apenas por coincidência.

Comment: A discussão gerada me fez aprender entre o "precisa ser assim" ou o que é semântico, creio que o equívoco da pergunta com o corpo da dúvida acabou por entender além do que necessitava para o caso. grato