# Calcular mais de um text box e exibir em um text box especifico

Tags: c#

Bom dia pessoal,
 estou quebrando a cabeça de como proceder com tal lógica;

Gostaria de pegar o valor desses 4 textbox (txtDinheiro, txtCheque, txtCredito e txtDebito)

e no final ir fazendo o processo aritmético no txtRestante.

Exemplo seria se o cliente for pagar em mais de uma forma de pagamento (dinheiro e débito) que os 2 subtraisse e mostraria no restante até igualar ao valor total.

Segue a imagem da parte de pagamento do meu PDV

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque um pouco do seu código, o que é que já  tentou fazer ou  tem feito? Está com problemas em converter os valores da string?

Comment: O código esta dessa forma funciona só que só pro txtbox cheque queria fazer o processo nos outros 3 tipos de pagamento também e resultar no restante:

void Pagamento()
        {
            if (Convert.ToDecimal(txtCheque.Text) <= valor)
            {
                valcheque = Convert.ToDecimal(txtCheque.Text);
                txtRestante.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", valor - valcheque);
            }
            else
            {
                txtRestante.Text = String.Format("{0:c}", restante);
            }
        }

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma classe, que represente o pagamento, e associar um objeto dessa classe no `DataBind` dos `textBox`. Os cálculos são todos realizados na classe, o Form só se encarrega da exibição.

Fiz um exemplo:

```
 public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        Pagamento objPg;



        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            objPg = new Pagamento();


            textBoxDinheiro.DataBindings.Add("Text", objPg, "Dinheiro", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            textBoxCredito.DataBindings.Add("Text", objPg, "Credito", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            textBoxDebito.DataBindings.Add("Text", objPg, "Debito", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            textBoxCheque.DataBindings.Add("Text", objPg, "Cheque", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            textBoxTotal.DataBindings.Add("Text", objPg, "TotalVenda", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            textBoxTotalPago.DataBindings.Add("Text", objPg, "TotalPago", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            textBoxRestante.DataBindings.Add("Text", objPg, "Restante", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
            textBoxTroco.DataBindings.Add("Text", objPg, "Troco", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);


        }
    }


    public class Pagamento
    {
        public decimal Dinheiro { get; set; }
        public decimal Credito { get; set; }
        public decimal Debito { get; set; }
        public decimal Cheque { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalVenda { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPago { get { return Dinheiro + Credito + Debito + Cheque; } }
        public decimal Restante { get { return TotalPago > TotalVenda ? 0 : TotalVenda - TotalPago; } }
        public decimal Troco { get { return TotalPago > TotalVenda ? TotalPago - TotalVenda : 0; } }
    }
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Há ainda como formatar para moeda: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> Sugestão: Não utilize 'ESC' (Escape) para concluir a venda. Me parece algo como "Pressione Delete para Gravar"

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei em que programa ou língua estás a fazer mas aqui está a minha solução.

Eu não percebo muito das contas, mas presumo que o débito seja o que ele deve em dinheiro ou cartão, então primeiro vamos somar todas as maneiras que ele pode ter usado para pagar, o que vai ser igual ao valor que está a pagar.
E no outro vamos subtrair o que deve ao que ele está a pagar para ter o troco.

Assim:

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
int resultado;
int valor_pago;
int valor_total_a_pagar;

txtDinheiro.Text = a;
txtCheque.Text = b;
txtCredito.Text = c;
txtDebito.Text = d;

a + b + c = valor_pago;
a + b + c - valor_total_a_pagar = resultado;

valorpago.Text = valor_pago;
troco.Text = resultado;
label1.Text = valor_total_a_pagar;
```

Comment: e se a venda for R$10,50 ? Você não pode atribuir uma variavel `int` a uma string `Text`, Isso: `valorpago.Text = valor_pago;` vai dar erro de compilação. Valeu a intenção em ajudar, mas esse código não irá funcionar.

Comment: Substituir o int pelo double

Comment: o correto é decimal. Veja isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/59016/69359