# Comparação de variáveis de tipo diferente com conversão retorna resultado incorreto

Tags: delphi, tipagem

Tenho o seguinte código

```
var
  Valor1: string;
  Valor2: Double;
begin
  Valor1 := '150.15';
  Valor2 := 150.15;

  If StrToFloat(Valor1) = Valor2 then
     ShowMessage('Iguais');
end;
```

Nesta situação, as vezes o Delphi entende que os valores são diferentes, porém, se utilizo o código abaixo eles são considerados iguais

```
    var
      Valor1: string;
      Valor2: Double;
  Valor2: Double;
    begin
      Valor1 := '150.15';
      Valor2 := 150.15;
      Valor3 :=  StrToFloat(Valor1);

      If Valor3 = Valor2 then
         ShowMessage('Iguais');
    end;
```

Observação: no exemplo citado estou definindo os valores diretamente para a variável, porém, o problema que eu tive ocorria da leitura de um dado da serial, mas mesmo que eu utiliza-se a função `FormatFloat` isso continuava ocorrendo, e se eu desse um *debug* nas variáveis os valores estavam iguais, e ainda assim não eram considerados iguais no `if`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você precisa de igualdade exata não pode usar um `Double`. Não é possível em todos os casos. Ele tem um formato binário que não pode representar todos os números possível, então algo que parece o mesmo pode não ser, depende da forma que foi obtido. Veja [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Não sei ao certo no Delphi porque ocorre a diferença. Ou esse código é um pouco diferente do real onde obteve o resultado, ou a linguagem tem alguma otimização que traz um resultado diferente, o que é estranho, afinal o fato de armazenar em uma variável não deveria trocar a semântica, mas cada linguagem com sua preferência, já vimos nesta página que tem coisas esquisitas em Delphi. Pode ser que esteja interpretando alguma coisa equivocadamente.

`Extendend` não resolve o problema, afinal ele é um `Double` com mais precisão, mas ainda inexato, no máximo o disfarça, o que é pior. Funcionará, mas não estará certo. Pode ser que nunca dê erro, mas por definição pode dar.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Tem como resolver se espalhar arredondamentos pelo código todo, mas é gambi da grossa.

A única solução real é um tipo decimal no lugar de binário, o expoente binário não permite todos os valores (2) que estamos acostumados (10).

Não conheço a implementação do `Currency` do Delphi, ele seria a solução, mas pela observação do Bacco ele foi mal-feito (ambos não temos certeza). Um tipo decimal deveria ser em essência um inteiro, não necessariamente `Integer` com um expoente embutido indicado as casas decimais (tem outras formas de implementar isto). Aí funciona e está certo.

Tenho uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101) que é meio que um compêndio sobre o assunto.

[Exemplo correto em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40045/101).

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/59010/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Pascal/Conceptual.md).

Comment: não entendi o porque o `Extended` disfarça o resultado, uma vez que no Delphi ele representa um valor de ponto flutuante de alta precisão. pode explanar?

Comment: @JúniorMoreira veja a resposta linkada, o fato de ser ponto flutuante já indica que o valor real nao é o que você vê: [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/70)

Comment: @Bacco então, li e entende, o que gostaria que fosse explanado seria o "disfarça", no Delphi  o type cast tem que ser feito corretamente, se não o "disfarce" aparece. O retorno do `StrToFloat` par ao caso em questão esta sendo usado de forma incorreta, o `Extended` é um `Long Double`, o que entendo é que esta querendo guardar um caminhão na vaga de um fusca.

Comment: É diferente, o Long Double é um caminhão no lugar de um fusca. Se quer achar uma agulha em um deles em qual tem mais área pra procurar? Por isso que disfarça mais.

Comment: @JúniorMoreira você no primeiro comentário disse que ele representa ponto flutuante, agora disse que é long, não entendi direito. É float ou é long? Não tenho prática com os tipos específicos do Delphi.

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Acabo de ver um manual (muito ruim por sinal) que chama tudo de "decimal", misturando float com decimal (que são coisas completamente diferentes). O fato é que se Extended for igual o Long do C, ele é  inteiro e preciso. Se for igual o Float do C, é impreciso (e você não vê o valor exato na maior parte dos casos). Me pareceu que o unico tipo de valor com decimal sem problemas para Delphi seria o Currency

Comment: ... e mesmo assim, parece que ele só é "preciso" por forçar arredondamento no float. Eu teria que ver a implementação real para poder discorrer melhor. O fato é que qualquer coisa que não seja armazenada com valor literal não presta para operações financeiras. Se alguém com experiência em Delphi puder dar mais detalhes técnicos, agradeço.

Comment: @Bacco `O fato é que qualquer coisa que não seja armazenada com valor literal não presta para operações financeiras.` Aqui esta o ponto principal, tínhamos um problema com arredondamento, para resolver tivemos que mudar para `Numeric` (Firebird) e no Delphi o encaixe foi o `Extended`, tudo que era `Real`, `Double` dava problema. O Numeric parou de gravar "xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" do DoublePrecision/Float e passou a gravar exatamente o que enviávamos. Agora alguém com experiência maior no assunto seria muito bem vindo.

Comment: Ou seja, disfarçou melhor e agora não estão vendo mais o problema, mas ele está lá pronto para explodir em algum momento. Pena que eu não posso colocar uma imagem em comentário...

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Eu não teria muito a acrescentar, seria o caso de uma lida com carinho no post que o Maniero linkou, ele trata do problema independente da linguagem e da plataforma. O Firebird tem uma coisa interessante, você pode usar Int, mas com escala (-2, por exemplo) para os decimais. Assim, com certeza o numero que está vendo é o que foi armazenado. Um float, que parece na tela como 2.5000000000 pode internamente estar armazenado como 2.4999999999999999999999938271, e você só vai perceber quando os resultados não baterem. É da natureza do float.

Comment: Um int com escala -2 já seria assim: 2,50, internamente armazenado como 250 (0x000000FA), não tem onde dar errado. E isso serve pra qualquer situação, pois se o DB ou a linguagem não tem tipo nativo, você pode criar suas próprias funções para isso. De qualquer jeito o sistema vai ter que lidar com arredondamento mesmo, e isso quem define é a regra de negócio ou legislação, e não a linguagem. Ou faz como a nossa secretaria da fazenda, que numa piada digna de Brasil, aceita erros de um centavo em determinadas situações.

Answer (score 3):

Se vai utilizar a função `StrToFloat` considere passar para ela uma string com ',' e não '.' para separador decimal.

Outro detalhe é o Tipo da Variavel que vai receber o resultado.

Na `System.SysUtils` temos:

`function StrToFloat(const S: string): Extended;`

```
var
  Valor1: string;
  Valor2: Extended;
begin
  Valor1 := '150,15';
  Valor2 := 150.15;

  If StrToFloat(Valor1) = Valor2 then
     ShowMessage('Iguais');
```

Comment: Só um detalhe, o separador decimal pode ser variável entre '.' e ','  conforme as definições do formatsettings. Se não inicializada pelo sistema, é pego as configurações regionais do windows como padrão.